# Security problems regarding +FollowSymLinks and -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using this for one of my applications:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

And I worry about the security problems this may bring. Any idea what measures I can take to make this approach as secure as possible?

Comment: [The official Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) has the following to say about FollowSymLinks: "Omitting this option should not be considered a security restriction, since symlink testing is subject to race conditions that make it circumventable."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing specific you can do to make using those options as secure as possible. The risk in using them is that a user, or a process running under a user, can disclose information or even hijack content by creating symlinks. For example, if an unpriviliged user (who may have been compromised) wants to read a file that they normally can't, they can sort of escalate it by creating a symlink from their public_html directory to it, and if apache can read it, they can then just access their webpage and read the file. There's nothing specific you can do to prevent something like that from happening except to make sure you're system is properly patched and configured.

Note that this threat isn't just from users on your system. If you are running a webapp in, say php, and it got compromised somehow, an attacker can upload a php file browser and create symlinks to content outside of your document root (like to /etc/passwd or some other file you don't want exposed to the web).

If you're worried about stuff like that, it's better not to use these options.